# How to alter jQuery code to only allow jpg files

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function that allows the user to upload images.  Admittedly I know very little about jQuery but I need to be able to change this code slightly.  At the moment it will throw an error if a file that isn't an image is used but I would like it to throw an error is a that file isn't a jpg, JPG, jpeg or JPEG.

I'm not sure how much of the original code is needed but this is the section that does the filtering.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

    // Makes sure the dataTransfer information is sent when we
    // Drop the item in the drop box.
    jQuery.event.props.push('dataTransfer');

    var z = -40;
    // The number of images to display
    var maxFiles = 5;
    var errMessage = 0;

    // Get all of the data URIs and put them in an array
    var dataArray = [];

    // Bind the drop event to the dropzone.
    $('#drop-files').bind('drop', function(e) {

        // Stop the default action, which is to redirect the page
        // To the dropped file

        var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
        var ext = $('#drop-files').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();


        // Show the upload holder
        $('#uploaded-holder').show();

        // For each file
        $.each(files, function(index, file) {
            // Some error messaging
            if (!files[index].type.match('image.*')) {

                if(errMessage == 0) {
                    $('#drop-files').html('Only jpg files are allowed');

                }

                return false;
            }

            // Check length of the total image elements

            if($('#dropped-files > .image').length < maxFiles) {
                // Change position of the upload button so it is centered
                var imageWidths = ((220 + (40 * $('#dropped-files > .image').length)) / 2) - 20;
                $('#upload-button').css({'left' : imageWidths+'px', 'display' : 'block'});
            }

            // Start a new instance of FileReader
            var fileReader = new FileReader();

                // When the filereader loads initiate a function
                fileReader.onload = (function(file) {

                    return function(e) { 

                        // Push the data URI into an array
                        dataArray.push({name : file.name, value : this.result});

                        // Move each image 40 more pixels across
                        z = z+40;
                        var image = this.result;


                        // Just some grammatical adjustments
                        if(dataArray.length == 1) {
                            $('#upload-button span').html("1 file to be uploaded");
                        } else {
                            $('#upload-button span').html(dataArray.length+" files to be uploaded");
                        }
                        // Place extra files in a list
                        if($('#dropped-files > .image').length < maxFiles) { 
                            // Place the image inside the dropzone
                            $('#dropped-files').append('<div class="image" style="left: '+z+'px; background: url('+image+'); background-size: cover;"> </div>'); 
                        }
                        else {

                            $('#extra-files .number').html('+'+($('#file-list li').length + 1));
                            // Show the extra files dialogue
                            $('#extra-files').show();

                            // Start adding the file name to the file list
                            $('#extra-files #file-list ul').append('<li>'+file.name+'</li>');

                        }
                    }; 

                })(files[index]);

            // For data URI purposes
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

        });


    });

    function restartFiles() {

        // This is to set the loading bar back to its default state
        $('#loading-bar .loading-color').css({'width' : '0%'});
        $('#loading').css({'display' : 'none'});
        $('#loading-content').html(' ');
        // --------------------------------------------------------

        // We need to remove all the images and li elements as
        // appropriate. We'll also make the upload button disappear

        $('#upload-button').hide();
        $('#dropped-files > .image').remove();
        $('#extra-files #file-list li').remove();
        $('#extra-files').hide();
        $('#uploaded-holder').hide();

        // And finally, empty the array/set z to -40
        dataArray.length = 0;
        z = -40;

        return false;
    }

    $('#upload-button .upload').click(function() {

        $("#loading").show();
        var totalPercent = 100 / dataArray.length;
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;

        $('#loading-content').html('Uploading '+dataArray[0].name);

        $.each(dataArray, function(index, file) {   

            $.post('upload.php', dataArray[index], function(data) {

                var fileName = dataArray[index].name;
                ++x;

                // Change the bar to represent how much has loaded
                $('#loading-bar .loading-color').css({'width' : totalPercent*(x)+'%'});

                if(totalPercent*(x) == 100) {
                    // Show the upload is complete
                    $('#loading-content').html('Uploading Complete!');
                    window.location = "http://www.dentaldigs.co.uk/upload_success.php";

                    // Reset everything when the loading is completed
                    setTimeout(restartFiles, 500);

                } else if(totalPercent*(x) < 100) {

                    // Show that the files are uploading
                    $('#loading-content').html('Uploading '+fileName);

                }

                // Show a message showing the file URL.
                var dataSplit = data.split(':');
                if(dataSplit[1] == 'upload successful') {
                    var realData = '<li><a href="images/'+dataSplit[0]+'">'+fileName+'</a> '+dataSplit[1]+'</li>';

                    $('#uploaded-files').append('<li><a href="images/'+dataSplit[0]+'">'+fileName+'</a> '+dataSplit[1]+'</li>');

                    // Add things to local storage 
                    if(window.localStorage.length == 0) {
                        y = 0;
                    } else {
                        y = window.localStorage.length;
                    }

                    window.localStorage.setItem(y, realData);

                } else {
                    $('#uploaded-files').append('<li><a href="images/'+data+'. File Name: '+dataArray[index].name+'</li>');
                }

            });
        });

        return false;
    });

    // Just some styling for the drop file container.
    $('#drop-files').bind('dragenter', function() {
        $(this).css({'box-shadow' : 'inset 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)', 'border' : '4px dashed #B3C234'});
        return false;
    });



    $('#drop-files').bind('drop', function() {
        $(this).css({'box-shadow' : 'none', 'border' : '4px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)'});
        return false;
    });

    // Let them know that they aren’t in the correct dragenter zone
    $('#drop-files').bind('dragleave', function() {
    $(this).css({'box-shadow' : 'none', 'border' : '4px dashed rgba(0,0,0,0.2)'});
    return false;
    });

    // For the file list
    $('#extra-files .number').toggle(function() {
        $('#file-list').show();
    }, function() {
        $('#file-list').hide();
    });

    $('#dropped-files #upload-button .delete').click(restartFiles);

    // Append the localstorage the the uploaded files section
    if(window.localStorage.length > 0) {
        $('#uploaded-files').show();
        for (var t = 0; t < window.localStorage.length; t++) {
            var key = window.localStorage.key(t);
            var value = window.localStorage[key];
            // Append the list items
            if(value != undefined || value != '') {
                $('#uploaded-files').append(value);
            }
        }
    } else {
        $('#uploaded-files').hide();
    }
});
```

At the moment this will allow any image type and I need it to just allow jpg, JPG, jpeg and JPEG

Comment: We'll need the rest of the code, or the contents of `e.dataTransfer`. After `var files = e.dataTransfer.files`, could you add `console.log(files);` and paste the results in your question?

Comment: Remember to also do anologous testing on server-side.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld, I' afraid I am a complete noob at JQuery and I have no idea what you are asking me for, sorry

Comment: Just a quick point of order: make sure that you also verify on the server-side that the files are JPEG files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
if (!files[index].type.match('image.*')) {
```

into this:

```
if (!(files[index].type.match("image.*") && files[index].name.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg)$/i) ) ) {
```

It should then work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that but it still allows files that are not jpg or JPG to be uploaded.  Is there a way that I can limit the upload to certain files type such as jpg and JPG?

Comment: Thank you, had to make a slight modification so the line actually reads if (!(files[index].name.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg)$/i) ) ) {. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

What about deleting the unwanted files from the files array?

```
if (!files[index].type.match('image.*')) {

            if(errMessage == 0) {
                $('#drop-files').html('Only jpg files are allowed');

            }

            return false;
        }
        /* Remove file from the array if it doesnt match jpg | jpeg */
        else if ((files[index].name.match(/.+(jpg|jpeg)$/)){
            files.splice(index, 1);
            return;
        }
       ....
```

If the files are not in the files list they will not be read / uploaded

Comment: Thats a brilliant idea, only problem is that Dreamweaver flags the line else if(if... with an error

Comment: Sorry about that, there was an extra if left inside the else if condition, I have fixed that in the above code now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try regular expression?

```
 $.each(files, function(index, file) {
            // Some error messaging
            if (!files[index].type.match('image.*')) {
                    errMessage = 1;
                    var pattern = /(\.(?:jpg|jpeg|JPG|JPEG))$/gm;

                    if (!file.name.match(pattern)){
                    errMessage = 0
                    }
                if(errMessage == 0) {
                    $('#drop-files').html('Only jpg files are allowed');

                }

                return false;
            }
}
```

EDIT: code is untested. But hopefully will give an idea what I mean. Also it is assumed you're getting a file object in "file"

Comment: Hi,  I'm afraid it still allows .png to be uploaded

Comment: Thanks for that, it still didn't work, I suspect the type.match argument stopped it from working in the same way it did in the solution by Sebastien Renauld.  Thank you for all of your help though